# How to integrate Jersey to Struts2+Hibernate application

Tags: hibernate, struts2, jersey

I've integrated Jersey to Struts2 application its working fine but in my web application i am using Hibernate, while i requesting any webservice,  getting hibernate session null so unable to do any db operations. I am using struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin for session. Please tell me proper configuration for jersey integration to Struts2 with hibernate.

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JerseyRESTService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.healthouts.webservices</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JerseyRESTService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Hidocs</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>    


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            60
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <!--<welcome-file>LoginForm1.jsp</welcome-file>-->
        <welcome-file>homepage.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/pages/error404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>


</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```xml
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="20971540" />

    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest/.*?" />
    <!--<plug-in className="com.voxmojo.controller.listener.QuartzSchedulerListener" />-->
    <include file="signup.xml"/>
    <include file="defaultweb.xml"/>
    <include file="login.xml"/>
    <include file="consumer.xml" />
    <include file="doctor.xml" />
    <include file="payment.xml" />
    <include file="admin.xml" />
    <include file="hospital.xml" />
    <include file="app.xml" />
    <!--<include file="bog.xml" />-->

    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">
        <action name="">
            <result>index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="SimpleWays">
            <result>blog1.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Youknowwhat">
            <result>blog2.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="The5essentials">
            <result>blog3.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="10VegetarianLunchIdeas">
            <result>blog4.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="HowToHaveAProblem-FREE">
            <result>blog5.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="HaveAGoalthasBigger">
            <result>blog6.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Fruits">
            <result>blog7.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="5-Herbal-Tips-to-take-care-of-your-Hair">
            <result>blogHerbalTips.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="7-Foods-that-help-keep-digestion">
            <result>7Foodsthathelpkeepdigestion.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="6-Tips-to-keep-mosquito-out-of-your-home">
            <result>6Tipstokeepmosquitooutofyourhome.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="9-side-effects-of-Junk-Food">
            <result>9side-effectsofJunkFood.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="5-Tips-to-get-rid-of-body-odor">
            <result>5Tipstogetridofbodyodor.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="7-Herbal-tips-to-anticipate-acnes-and-flaws">
            <result>7Herbaltipstoanticipateacnesandflaws.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="6-Tips-to-anticipate-cold-this-winter">
            <result>6Tipstoanticipatecoldthiswinter.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="5-herbal-oils-you-did-not-know-are-good-for-your-hairs">
            <result>5HerbalOilsYouDidNotKnowAreGoodForYourHairs.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="5-natural-products-just-made-for-your-skin">
            <result>5NaturalProductsJustMadeForYourSkin.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="DIABETIC-GOALS-THAT-EVERY-DIABETIC-IS-SUPPOSED-TO-KNOW-REMEMBER">
            <result>DiabeticGoals.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="gastroparesis-and-diabetes-another-aspect-of-neuropathy">
            <result>Gastroparesis-and-Diabetes.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="ordering-your-exercise-to-avoid-hypoglycemia">
            <result>ordering-your-exercise-to-avoid-hypoglycemia.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="joslin-researchers-on-type-1-mortality-theres-still-more-to-be-done">
            <result>joslin-researchers-on-type-1-mortality-theres-still-more-to-be-done.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="diabetes-and-your-brain-a-joslin-roundtable">
            <result>diabetes-and-your-brain-a-joslin-roundtable.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

Comment: Look at the examples on jersey site.

Comment: And where is your code? Where are you getting null?